# NavBar always overlap the Main Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

> This is my Main Content (which is basically a table with some data). As you can see it goes under the TopNav and SideNav. Below is the code of my php file. I tried everything  but still it doesnt get fixed .

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<?php include 'navbar.php';?>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mainContainer">
    <section  class="main_content_right">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] !='') 
                        {
                            echo '
                            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> '.$_SESSION['status'].'
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            ';
                            unset($_SESSION['status']);
                        }
                    ?>
                   
        </div>
    </section>

     </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</body>
```

> This is my `sideNav` :

```
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
<div id="layoutSidenav">
<div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
<nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                    <div class="nav">
                        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading"></div>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="home.php">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                            Dashboard
                        </a>
                        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#collapseLayouts" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
                            Layouts
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseLayouts" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                            <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="layout-static.html">Static Navigation</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="layout-sidenav-light.html">Light Sidenav</a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsePages"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></div>
                            Pages
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapsePages" aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                            data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                            <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav accordion" id="sidenavAccordionPages">
                                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseAuth" aria-expanded="false"
                                    aria-controls="pagesCollapseAuth">
                                    Authentication
                                    <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseAuth" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                                    data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                                    <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseError" aria-expanded="false"
                                    aria-controls="pagesCollapseError">
                                    Error
                                    <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseError" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                                    data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                                    <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="401.html">401 Page</a>
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="500.html">500 Page</a>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Addons</div>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i></div>
                            Charts
                        </a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                            Tables
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                    <div class="small">Copyright &copy;
                   <a href="https://codecanyon.net/user/zibrangni/portfolio" > Zibrangni</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
</div>

</div>
            
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
```

> I tried using the Bootstrap class :  `class="main_content_right"` , and also `class="mainContainer"` but got no luck !

> What am I missing , Please let me know ? I am new to Web dev

Comment: To help others understand your issue and to aid in finding a solution I would recommend you provide a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you are facing. It's possible that the process of doing so sheds new light on the problem at hand. Regardless it will aid others in helping you. Please consider this when next posting a question, to aid in solving your future problems as quickly as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced in Bootstrap but it seems like the issue is that you have set the navbar to `position: fixed` and now it is coming on top of the other content. If I was in a similar situation I would most likely add a margin to the main content. E.g. if the navbar is 100px on the left and 40px on the top, just add that margin to the main content and you should be good to go!